# .net core 3.1 Azure Deploy issues 500 then 404

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

[Image #1 from "Help Support"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHSu5.png)

[Image #2 from "Help Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF5Ic.png)

[Image #3 from "Help Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXavu.png)

First off THANK YOU for looking at this and providing any help you might be able to provide me. I have a .net core 3.1 website I have deployed to azure and made changes and update regularly without and issue before. I updated it to .net core 3.1 recently and deployed it to azure without any issues. I then made more changes and updated it and not get 500 error and clearly can not assess the site online anymore. I initially got a 500 error and then removed a some code that i thought was incomplete from my startup.cs file that was for AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn nugget package. I then redeployed and got a 404 error. I am a bit lost since i get no errors on local host. At no point have I had any issues with loading my site on local host. I have included images from the "help / support" part in azure. I do see it is asking me to move up to higher tier. I had been using the highest option of dev/test with no issues before. Is that issue? I doubted it since i had never had issues before.

Please feel free to ask any questions you might have. I am still looking for answers on my own and plan to post an answer if i can find one on my own but am feeling a bit stuck. Thank you for any help you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

The "App Service Plan Density Check" and "SNAT Port Exhaustion" were do to being on too low of tier. The rest was due to me updating code but then not creating a new "App Service". If you are updating to .net core 3.1 create a new "App Service" with 3.1 from the beginning and everything should work. Using my older "App Service" instance did work for a while but ultimately broke.